# Use Proxy to redirect my Site?

Tags: apache

> > I want to redirect my Apache Server to my node server running on other
> >     port on localhost  Like when i enter localhost:80 it should redirect my node server which is running on localhost:3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:3000> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/example/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/example/
</VirtualHost>
```